# Linux Apache PHP: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, apache

Apache and PHP are installed right now.
I test my php code which is right on windows.

> Chrome report page can not load:ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

It seems `$_POST` do not work.

note.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  _SESSION['note']='<p>'.$_POST['text'].'</p>'.$_SESSION['note'];
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <title>Note</title>
    <form method="post" action="note.php" name=form1>
      <input type="text" name="text" size=100 required>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" name="B1">
      <input type="reset" value="reset" name="B2">
    </form>
    <?php
      echo $_SESSION['note'];
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Change the form to GET method, it works well.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['note']='<p>'.$_GET['text'].'</p>'.$_SESSION['note'];
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <title>Note</title>
    <form method="get" action="note.php" name=form1>
      <input type="text" name="text" size=100>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" name="B1">
      <input type="reset" value="reset" name="B2">
    </form>
    <?php
      echo $_SESSION['note'];
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are getting post with the session then assigning it back to the session which is strange.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. My problem was that I had some invalid settings in the `.htaccess` file. It could be a good idea to deactivate line by line in the htaccess to see if that's causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

I tested you code on Linux (Ubuntu) and it works fine. Perhaps you have problems with how you configured the web server. Few tips

- Was there an error message in **/var/log/apache2/error.log**?
- Is **mod PHP enabled in Apache**? Is it enabled for the directory your file is in (e.g. in userdir)?
- Does the file have proper **file permissions** to be read by the www user?
- Did you change anything in **php.ini?**

Comment: [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]

Comment: Not sure what that means. Are you using SSL/https? If so you probably have a problem with how you configured  the site.

Comment: New error: [notice] child pid 1964 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)